# Embed HTML YouTube Video; Displaying Incorrectly

Tags: css, youtube, embed, html

I'm building a webpage using DreamWeaver from scratch (no template). It's for a school project.

My DIV formatting was fine until I tried to embed the YouTube video. Why is my YouTube video stuck directly beneath the header? Also, the DIV/Table on the right side of the page is also out of whack. It just want the YT video on the left and the table on the right, and I want them to line up horizontally.

Thanks for any assistance. [Click to view the Webpage, with obvious errors.](http://fambook.co.nf/)

CODE:

HTML-

```
<!DOCTYPE>

<html>

<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="FamilyBookMain.css">

</head>

<title>FamilyBook.com</title>

<body>
<div id="top">
</div>

<div class="video-container">
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/MQgdE1_lHnA?rel=0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
       <div class="famtree">
<img src="images/fambooktree.png" width="705" height="221"/>   
    </div>
 </div>



<div id="body">
   <table style="border-collapse:collapse;">
        <thead>

<h1>Your Ancestors Are Dead.</h1> 
<h1>But Here, They're Still Alive.</h1>
            <br>

        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="padding:10px"> 
                <p class="table"><br>Welcome to the world's <strong>largest</strong> online resource for social media profiles and data from the twenty-first century. FamilyBook.com is home to billions of profiles from MySpace, FaceBook, Twitter, Instagram, and more. <br> <br> 
                We are the <strong>leading provider of social media data</strong> from the early 2000s, including searchable image tags, status updates, relationship histories, friendships and family networks. Our mission is to link people to the personal histories of their ancestors- one social media profile at a time.</p></td> </tr>

               <tr><td style="padding:10px">
                <p class="table">
                Imagine the stories that you'll uncover as you explore your loved one's Facebook timeline and likes, private messages and chat logs, Twitter conversations, and Instagram uploads. The <strong>secrets</strong> that you uncover may even surprise you.<br>

               <br> Simply start with a name and <strong>we'll do the rest.
                </strong> Discover your ancestor's past. Learn where you came from. <br> 
                </p></td>     
            </tr>
        </tbody>
           <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="head" colspan="2">
                <strong>Our services are coming soon!</strong><br><br>

            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
    </div>   


<div class="footer">
<p id="footer"><img src="http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v483/CrazyInsaneJess/familybook.png" width="139" height="25"/>
<br>Jessica E. Tompkins 2014 | <a href="http://en.gravatar.com/jesstompkins"> About</a>
</p>
</div>


</body>

</html>
```

CSS-

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

body {
background-color:#EEEEEE;
position: fixed;

}

#top {
width: 100%;
height: 60px;
background-   image:url('http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v483/CrazyInsaneJess/familybook.png');
background-color:#FFF;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:60px bottom;
border-bottom-width:thin;
border-bottom-color: #333;
border-bottom-style:solid;
position: fixed;
top: 0px;
}

#body {
width: 550px;
height: 400px;
background-color: #99aabb;
text-align: right;
margin: 10px;
position: relative;
left: 650px;
bottom: 215px;
}

h1 {
color: #333;
font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
text-align: center;
margin: 0px;
top: 10px;
position: relative;
}

.video {
position: relative;
left:170px;
top: 170px;
}


ul.crap {
color: #333;
font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
font-size:12px;
}

#video {
color: #99aacc;
font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
text-align: center;
height: 200;
width: 450;
margin: 350px 0px 0px;
position: absolute;
}

.table {
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
text-align:left;
font-size:14px;
color: white;
}

.head {
color: #333;
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size:16px;
padding: 15px;
font-weight:100;
}

.footer{
width: 100%;
height: 60px;
background-color: #99aacc;
border:1px solid #333;
position:fixed;
bottom:0px;
}

#footer{
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:9px;
padding:5px;
color: white;
text-align:center;
}

a {
text-decoration:none;
}
```

Comment: You have several IDs and classes that are not begin used, but that's not the problem ;) You could maybe create a wrapper, something to hold the table and the video together, both having `float:left` and the wrapper having `overflow:auto`. Do you want to center align them to the center of the page as well? Cool assignment btw, way cooler than the ones I had in school

Comment: Just for the record, this question would probably be a better fit for codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Hi @JessT, I noticed that you updated your website to include my suggested changes. If my answer solved your issue, please accept it by pressing the check mark. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, welcome to StackOverflow. I only spent about a minute looking over and editing your code, but I think I get the gist of what you want to do. Please see the code below:

Change your `#body` element to match the code below: (I positioned the div absolutely.)

```
  #body {
width: 550px;
height: 400px;
background-color: #99aabb;
text-align: right;
margin: 10px;
position: absolute;
left: 650px;
top:65px
}
```

Paste this into your CSS:

```
.video-container{
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    margin-top:75px;

}
```

Now, let me just say that your HTML kind of messy and could be streamlined quite a bit. As @Havard Brynjulfsen pointed out, there are a few IDs and classes that remain unused. In any case, the code above, should yield the desired results, but what you are trying to do could be accomplished much more elegantly if you are willing to change up your HTML structure.

Also, there are some bugs in your HTML. I would highly suggest validating your code with the official [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/).

There are too many issues for me to list here without going off-topic, but here are the biggies:

1. Your doctype declaration is incorrect, it should be `<!DOCTYPE html>`.
2. Your `<title>` should be in the `<head>` of your document.